# Ubuntu 12.04 - upgraded to PHP5.4 - error on PHP Suhosin

Tags: 12.04, php

I have a Linode VPS with Ubuntu 12.04.

I had PHP5.3.10 installed and I just upgraded to PHP5.4.30 - by following the instructions given at http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-install-latest-php-5-4-x-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/

Everything is all good, except, I must have had PHP-SUHOSIN installed (I can't remember, but when I was setting up Linode, it recommended me to do so) and now I'm getting the following message.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I tried

> apt-get install php5-suhosin

But I'm getting

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  php5-common :
>   Conflicts: php5-suhosin but 0.9.33-1 is to be installed  php5-suhosin
>   : Depends: phpapi-20090626 
>   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve
>   generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - php5-suhosin wasn't available for PHP 5.4+ for a long time and thus the package was broken since PHP 5.4.  Suhosin upstream author has only recently updated suhosin to support PHP 5.4, but I am not going to prepare php5-suhosin package in my PPA since I don't think it's necessary with recent PHP releases.

And since you clearly don't remember why you had php5-suhosin installed I think you'll be fine without it.